# Форматирование HTML кода в NetBeans

Tags: веб-дизайн, веб-программирование, графика, вёрстка, netbeans

Доброе время суток форумчане, у меня возникло несколько вопросов по редактору "NetBeans"

1. При создании html столкнулся с небольшой проблемой: указания кодировки цвета в html коде (т.е. например #DDECFE) 
   **Существует возможность в данном редакторе выбирать цвет визуально, и сразу видеть его код?**
2. Например, при редактировании готовой таблицы, менять ширину колонок, просто перетягиванием (курсором мышки) соответствующую колонку таблицы, тем самым меняя соответствующий код html? Или вставлять рисунок в html документ с помощью той же мышки, стразу редактируя html-код.  Такая возможность есть в редакторе "*Adobe Dreamweaver*", но т.к. я перешел на NetBeans, было бы хорошо, чтобы и тут такая возможность была. **Может существует какой-то plug-in, выполняющий такую функцию?**

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Нет. И нету никаких плагинов.

Comment: А вот https://netbeans.org/community/magazine/html/03/visualwebdev/, на другом сайте я спрашивал. Но это как я посмотрю не совсем то, скорее для Java приложений, а нужно для html страничек. Или я ошибаюсь?